# Lockscreen on suspend (LightDM)

Tags: lightdm, lock-screen, 21.04

Currently I'm using LightDM with the lightdm-webkit2-greeter and multiple WM/DM's.

```
I3, AwesomeWM, Gnome and KDE
```

My problem is that on auto suspend or closing my laptop lid the screen either wont lock  when using gnome, or that I will get a different lock screen which I'm unable to identify.

I know that LightDM has some problems with locking your screen on suspend but there has to be a way?
My first question is, what kind of Lock screen Am I looking at?

[The Lockscreen in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7HHz.jpg)

Sorry for the phone picture, I was unable to make a screenshot

The second one would be, how can I make LightDM lock my screen on suspend or closing my laptop?

I already tried to create a service with systemd but that doesn't work for me, here is the script anyways:

Actually I tried 3 different ones I found on the web, but none of them works.

First one

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock screen when waking up

[Service]
User=%I
Type=forking
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dm-tool lock

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

Second

```
[Unit]
Description=Turning i3lock on before sleep
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=forking
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dm-tool lock
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

And the third one

```
[Unit]
Description=Turning light-locker on before sleep
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=forking
Enviroment=XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
ExecSart=/usr/bin/dm-tool lock
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

I'm sorry if I'm missing something trivial, but i never worked with services before
And just to clear it up, yes I enabled and started them with systemd

```
sudo systemctl enable xyz.service
```

I might need to mention that I use a program called howdy to unlock my laptop with my face, I had the problem before, but I'm unsure if it might affect a solution in any way.

Locking the screen manual with dm-tool or light-locker works.

Answer (score 0):

I got the last one to start with changing Enviro**n**ment and ExecS**t**art. I also don't know what the `User=%I` does, but you should check it out with `systemctl status file.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Turning light-locker on before sleep
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dm-tool lock
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

As for the oddball lock screen, see if you can catch a snapshot of what's running using `ps` - either temporarily in the service or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>.